# Table cuts in half when printing

Tags: jquery, css, printing

How can I avoid this happening? I don't want to go through PDF print solutions. Is there a way to handle this by CSS if not, is there a way I can check each row's position on the page and if they pass certain limit I give them top margin?

below is the table code that prints out and cuts at certain point.

```
<table class="view-table" id="table">
<tbody class="vt-section">
            <!--Title-->
            <tr data-holder="top_title" class="top_title">
                <th class="title">Income</th>
            <th class="title thSection">July<br>2016</th><th class="title thSection">August<br>2016</th><th class="title thSection">September<br>2016</th><th class="title undefined">TOTALS</th></tr>
            <!--Data-->
            <tr data-holder="inc_food">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Food</th>
            <td undefined="">$26,542.00</td><td undefined="">$25,955.00</td><td undefined="">$26,067.00</td><td class="bold">$78,564.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_non_food">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Non-Food</th>
            <td undefined="">$3,507.00</td><td undefined="">$3,020.00</td><td undefined="">$3,054.00</td><td class="bold">$9,581.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_gasoline">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Gasoline</th>
            <td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_retail">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Retail</th>
            <td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_wholesale">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Wholesale</th>
            <td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <!--Totals-->
            <tr data-holder="inc_total_sales">
                <th class="vt-label-un bold">Total Sales</th>
            <td class="incTotal">$30,049.00</td><td class="incTotal">$28,975.00</td><td class="incTotal">$29,121.00</td><td class="incFinal red bold">$88,145.00</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="vt-section">
            <!--Title-->
            <tr>
                <th class="title">Cost of Goods</th>
            </tr>
            <!--Data-->
            <tr data-holder="cogs_beginning_inventory">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Beginning Inventory</th>
            <td data-add="beginInv">$0.00</td><td data-add="beginInv">$0.00</td><td data-add="beginInv">$0.00</td><td class="empty"> </td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="cogs_food">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Food</th>
            <td data-add="cogs">$10,704.56</td><td data-add="cogs">$10,034.19</td><td data-add="cogs">$7,045.04</td><td class="bold">$27,783.79</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="cogs_non_food">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Non-Food</th>
            <td data-add="cogs">$8,943.93</td><td data-add="cogs">$7,442.25</td><td data-add="cogs">$5,462.66</td><td class="bold">$21,848.84</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="cogs_gasoline">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Gasoline</th>
            <td data-add="cogs">$0.00</td><td data-add="cogs">$0.00</td><td data-add="cogs">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="cogs_merchandise">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Merchandise</th>
            <td data-add="cogs">$1,373.65</td><td data-add="cogs">$1,640.40</td><td data-add="cogs">$503.52</td><td class="bold">$3,517.57</td></tr>
            <!--Totals-->
            <tr data-holder="cogs_ending_inventory">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Ending Inventory</th>
            <td data-add="endInv">$0.00</td><td data-add="endInv">$0.00</td><td data-add="endInv">$0.00</td><td class="empty"> </td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="vt-section">
            <!--Title-->
            <tr data-holder="cogs_total">
                <th class="title">COGS Total</th>
            <td class="cogsTotal bold">$21,022.14</td><td class="cogsTotal bold">$19,116.84</td><td class="cogsTotal bold">$13,011.22</td><td class="cogsFinal red bold">$53,150.20</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="cogs_gross_profit">
                <th class="vt-label-un bold">Gross Profit</th>
            <td class="grossProfit bold">$9,026.86</td><td class="grossProfit bold">$9,858.16</td><td class="grossProfit bold">$16,109.78</td><td class="grossFinal red bold">$34,994.80</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="vt-section">
            <!--Title-->
            <tr>
                <th class="title">Expenses</th>
            </tr>
            <!--Data-->
            <tr data-holder="exp_accounting">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Accounting</th>
            <td class="">$200.00</td><td class="">$675.00</td><td class="">$200.00</td><td class="bold">$1,075.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_advertisement">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Advertisement/Printing</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_alarm">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Alarm/Security</th>
            <td class="">$91.98</td><td class="">$91.98</td><td class="">$97.98</td><td class="bold">$281.94</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_auto">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Auto Expense</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_bank">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Bank-Misc Charges</th>
            <td class="">$497.59</td><td class="">$488.52</td><td class="">$479.35</td><td class="bold">$1,465.46</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_commission">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Comission</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_contributions">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Contributions</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_delivery">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Delivery/Freight</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_deprication">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Deprecation</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_equipment">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Equipment Rental</th>
            <td class="">$75.00</td><td class="">$75.00</td><td class="">$75.00</td><td class="bold">$225.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_fines">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Fines/Penalties</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_insurance">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Insurance</th>
            <td class="">$2,995.00</td><td class="">$344.65</td><td class="">$346.41</td><td class="bold">$3,686.06</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_interest">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Interest</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_laundry">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Laundry/Uniform</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_legal">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Legal/Accounting</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_license">
                <th class="vt-label-un">License/Dues/Fees</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_misc">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Miscellaneous</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_office">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Office Expense/Postage</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_outside">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Outside Services</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_payroll">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Payroll</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$10,400.00</td><td class="bold">$10,400.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_payroll_tax">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Payroll Tax</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$845.43</td><td class="bold">$845.43</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_pension">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Pension/401k</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_professional">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Professional Services</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_property">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Property Tax</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_rent">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Rent</th>
            <td class="">$2,500.00</td><td class="">$2,500.00</td><td class="">$2,500.00</td><td class="bold">$7,500.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_repairs">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Repairs/Maintenance</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_scavenger">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Scavenger/Extermination</th>
            <td class="">$262.88</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$264.96</td><td class="bold">$527.84</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_sub">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Sub Contractors</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_supplies">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Supplies and Materials</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$51.68</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$51.68</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_tax_sales">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Tax Sales</th>
            <td class="">$728.00</td><td class="">$675.00</td><td class="">$668.00</td><td class="bold">$2,071.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_tax_corporate">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Tax Corporate</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_tax_other">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Tax Other</th>
            <td class="">$42.00</td><td class="">$34.00</td><td class="">$36.00</td><td class="bold">$112.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_travel">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Travel/Entertainment</th>
            <td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_telephone">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Telephone</th>
            <td class="">$100.80</td><td class="">$354.90</td><td class="">$196.26</td><td class="bold">$651.96</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_utilities">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Utilities</th>
            <td class="">$1,012.47</td><td class="">$1,396.90</td><td class="">$1,126.07</td><td class="bold">$3,535.44</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="exp_total">
                <th class="vt-label-un bold">Expense Total</th>
            <td class="expTotal bold">$8,505.72</td><td class="expTotal bold">$6,687.63</td><td class="expTotal bold">$17,235.46</td><td class="expFinal red bold">$32,428.81</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="vt-section">
            <!--Title-->
            <tr data-holder="net_inc_loss">
                <th class="title">Net Income / Loss</th>
            <td class="netIncTotal">$521.14</td><td class="netIncTotal">$3,170.53</td><td class="netIncTotal">$-1,125.68</td><td class="netIncFinal red bold">$2,565.99</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_lottery">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Lottery Commission</th>
            <td class="netAdd">$376.54</td><td class="netAdd">$524.75</td><td class="netAdd">$412.02</td><td class="bold">$1,313.31</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_other">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Other Commission</th>
            <td class="netAdd">$0.00</td><td class="netAdd">$468.80</td><td class="netAdd">$288.80</td><td class="bold">$757.60</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="total_other_inc">
                <th class="vt-label-un bold">Total Other Income</th>
            <td class="otherIncTotal bold">$376.54</td><td class="otherIncTotal bold">$993.55</td><td class="otherIncTotal bold">$700.82</td><td class="totalOtherFinal  red bold">$2,070.91</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="vt-section">
            <!--Title-->
            <tr data-holder="total_inc_loss">
                <th class="title">TOTAL Income / Loss</th>
            <td class="netIncTotals bold">$897.68</td><td class="netIncTotals bold">$4,164.08</td><td class="netIncTotals bold">$-424.86</td><td class="bold  red">$4,636.90</td></tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding css - page-break-inside: avoid; for rows

Comment: that didn't really work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
table { page-break-inside:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
thead { display:table-header-group }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>x</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>x</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- 500 more rows -->
 <tr>
  <td>x</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while the answer might be obvious to you.  The answer is meant for the community.  In other words, for people who do not know how it works but would like to learn.  Adding an explanation about what the code does is a benefit to all newcomers

Comment: It still does samething. It cuts at exact same location.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a css file to print styles.

```
<link href="/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
```

Comment: Referring to `/print.css` is useless without saying what should go there.